# How can I find candidate key using FD.S?

Tags: dependencies, candidate-key

> VW->XYZ,
>   Z->W,
>   Y->VW

it is Funtional dependency relation  S{V,W,X,Y,Z}. candidate key is 'Y'??
or another??
I have a question. Why Z->W break normal form? and what type is broken normal form?

Answer (score 0):

The relation has three candidate keys:

```
1. Y
2. VW
3. VZ
```

and you can verify this by calculating the closure of each of them.

The relation is not in Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF), since in the dependency `Z → W` the determinant (`Z`) is not a superkey (while in the other two dependencies the determinants are keys).

Finally, note that the relation is in Third Normal Form (3NF), since `W` is a prime attribute (that is, is an attribute of a candidate key).

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. But, candidate key means minimal + unique. Because of it, I think vw, vz are not candidate key doesn,t it??

Comment: @analog_by, they **are** minimal, since minimal means “no other attribute can removed without losing the property of implying all the attributes of the table’ (it *does not* mean “constituted by a single attribute”!). So, `vw` and `vz` are minimal since you cannot remove any attribute from them without losing the fact of being keys (`v`, `w` and `z` alone **are not** keys).